# UIWebView Detect mp3 file loading

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my application i have `UIWebView` and i want to detect if a MP3 file is load(download).
So i use this `UIWebView` Delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = [request URL];


    if ([[[url pathExtension] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"mp3"]) {
        [self userDidClickUrl:url];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the URL is without mp3 string inside,and the UIWebView open the Native player. It's possible to detect it? I want to detect when a mp3 file is start loading.

Comment: Have you tried to set allowsInlineMediaPlayback property to YES ?

Comment: Swift 4 & ObjC [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072230/7576100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to detect  MIMEType based on your request - check if MIMEType from response is either one of those kind:
audio/mp3 || audio/mpeg3 || audio/x-mp3 || audio/x-mpeg3

Update: check this already answered:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType { 

NSURL *url = request.URL; 
NSURLRequest *req  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self]; 
[conn start];
return YES; } 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{ 

NSString *mime = [response MIMEType]; 
NSLog(@"%@",mime); }
```

Full link bellow:

[UIWebView Delegate get MIME Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257275/uiwebview-delegate-get-mime-type)

Comment: how to get response object from UIWebView?

Comment: @user3344236 in this http://musicplanet.in/bollywood-dl/24181-de-di-permission-ritu-pathak-mp3-song-download.html site when i click on download Now. Player is open and song is play but i can not get MIMEType such as audio/mp3 || audio/mpeg3 || audio/x-mp3 || audio/x-mpeg3 it give me MIMEType text/html so how i can get a MIMEType

Comment: You can try searching it by the response's first bytes if the server is not returning mime type, you can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916714/how-to-differentiate-if-nsdata-is-xls-ppt-or-doc-on-objective-c/34083139#34083139

Comment: Swift 4 & ObjC [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072230/7576100)