# How to differentiate if NSData is xls, ppt or doc on objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I'm working on a File-Handling type of app, I recently encountered a bug that is caused by links that doesn't have a file extension like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1234567abcdefghijk
```

I've been basing the file type by the filename located at the end of the link which is the direct link to the file.

In the case of a redirecting link like the google drive link above, it still returns the data but the problem is since it doesn't have a file extension, the `UIWebView` doesn't render the document types of file (I use a different viewer for image types and it renders quite fine because you can pass the data directly to a `UIImage`).

The solution I came up with was to check for **File Signature** which you can find in the first 1024 bytes of the data. I found the file signatures for document types in [http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php](http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search).

I can differentiate the images and pdf type of files but the problem is the xls/ppt/doc and xlsx/pptx/docx because they have the same file signatures, `[D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1]` and `[50 4B 03 04]` respectively.

***Now what I want to know is if there are other ways to differentiate those Microsoft Office document files.***

This is the code that I've already done, if you know how to enhance this function, I would accept it with some explanation:

```
typedef enum FileSignature {
    kFileSignaturePDF,
    kFileSignaturePPT_DOC_XLS,
    kFileSignaturePPTX_DOCX_XLSX,
    kFileSignaturePNG,
    kFileSignatureJPG,
    kFileSignatureBMP,
    kFileSignatureUndefined,
}FileSignature;

+ (FileSignature) getDocumentTypeOfData:(NSData *)documentData {

    if ( documentData.length >= 1024 ) {
        const unsigned char pdfBytes[] = {0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46};
        const unsigned char jpgBytes[] = {0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0};
        const unsigned char pngBytes[] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A};
        const unsigned char bmpBytes[] = {0x42, 0x4D};
        // pptx,xlsx,docx
        const unsigned char msOfficeXBytes[] = {0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 0x04};
        // ppt,xls,doc
        const unsigned char msOfficeBytes[] = {0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0xE1};

        NSString *pdfByteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:pdfBytes length:sizeof(pdfBytes) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *jpgByteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:jpgBytes length:sizeof(jpgBytes) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *pngByteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:pngBytes length:sizeof(pngBytes) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *bmpByteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bmpBytes length:sizeof(bmpBytes) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *msOfficeXByteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:msOfficeXBytes length:sizeof(msOfficeXBytes) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *msOfficeByteString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:msOfficeBytes length:sizeof(msOfficeBytes) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSArray *arrayOfBytesToSearchFor = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:pdfByteString,jpgByteString,pngByteString,bmpByteString, msOfficeByteString, msOfficeXByteString, nil];

        NSString *foundByteString = NULL;

        for (NSString *byteString in arrayOfBytesToSearchFor) {
            const unsigned char *searchForByte = (const unsigned char *) [byteString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            NSData *searchForByteData = [NSData dataWithBytes:searchForByte length:sizeof(searchForByte)];
            NSRange foundRange = [documentData rangeOfData:searchForByteData options:NSDataSearchAnchored range:NSMakeRange(0, 1024)];

            if (foundRange.length > 0) {
                foundByteString = byteString;
                break;
            }
        }

        FileSignature fileType = kFileSignatureUndefined;

        int indexOfFoundByteString = [arrayOfBytesToSearchFor indexOfObject:foundByteString];

        switch (indexOfFoundByteString) {
            case 0:
                fileType = kFileSignaturePDF;
                break;
            case 1:
                fileType = kFileSignatureJPG;
                break;
            case 2:
                fileType = kFileSignaturePNG;
                break;
            case 3:
                fileType = kFileSignatureBMP;
                break;
            case 4:
                fileType = kFileSignaturePPT_DOC_XLS;
                break;
            case 5:
                fileType = kFileSignaturePPTX_DOCX_XLSX;
                break;
            default:
                fileType = kFileSignatureUndefined;
                break;
        }

        return fileType;
    }

    return kFileSignatureUndefined;
}
```

Comment: Try [libmagic](https://github.com/threatstack/libmagic).

Comment: If that's an http(s) request, then the server will set the `content-type` in the HTTP response.  Can't you use that?

Comment: If there are no other clues available, attempt to parse as XML and failover to non-XML on an error.

Comment: @trojanfoe Never crossed my mind as that is beyond what I know until now, I'll try to research about how to get that `content-type` thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @PhillipMills Hmmm, that never crossed my mind as well, thanks as well for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to post this, but I went down on trojanfoe's idea of getting the `content-type` in the response header, if you are using **AFNetworking 2.0**  then on the success block you can get the content-type by `operation.response.allHeaderFields`, `allHeaderFields` is also a property of `NSHTTPURLResponse` for those doing the manual `NSURLConnection` way.

If you can do some improvements in this, be it optimization or lesser line of code or additions in the list of supported documents, I suggest you post an answer.

```
typedef enum DocumentType {
    kDocumentTypePDF,
    kDocumentTypePPT,
    kDocumentTypeDOC,
    kDocumentTypeXLS,
    kDocumentTypePPTX,
    kDocumentTypeDOCX,
    kDocumentTypeXLSX,
    kDocumentTypePNG,
    kDocumentTypeJPG,
    kDocumentTypeBMP,
    kDocumentTypeIMG,
    kDocumentTypeUndefined,
}DocumentType;

+ (DocumentType) getDocumentTypeBasedOnContentType:(NSString *)contentType {

    if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/pdf"] ) {
        return kDocumentTypePDF;
    } else if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/mspowerpoint"] ||
                [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/powerpoint"] ||
                [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"] ||
                [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/x-mspowerpoint"]) {
        return kDocumentTypePPT;
    } else if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/msword"] ) {
        return kDocumentTypeDOC;
    } else if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/excel"] ||
                [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.ms-excel"] ||
                [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/x-excel"] ||
                [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/x-msexcel"] ) {
        return kDocumentTypeXLS;
    }  else if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"] ) {
        return kDocumentTypeDOCX;
    }  else if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"] ) {
        return kDocumentTypePPTX;
    }  else if ( [contentType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"] ) {
        return kDocumentTypeXLSX;
    }   else if ( [contentType rangeOfString:@"image/"].location != NSNotFound ) {
        return kDocumentTypeIMG;
    } else {
        return kDocumentTypeUndefined;
    }

}
```